# CH3I + NaCl in acetone gives

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

How will methyl iodide react with $\ce{NaCl}$ in acetone?
According to me $S_N2$ reaction will take place where iodine will be replaced by chlorine and we will get $\ce{CH3Cl}$. Can anyone suggest why am I wrong and what will be the actual reaction?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.  In addition, the English language does not capitalize chemical names (including elements).  Stereochemical descriptors (like *E*, *Z*; *P*, *M*; *R*, *S*) are a different story, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be no reaction

The solubility of NaCl in acetone is 0.42mg per kilogram of acetone (source Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride)). This means that there is insufficient NaCl in solution for any reaction to occur.